# How to use LEFT JOIN and limit result to one row based on a count

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

Let's say i have 3 tables:

Table 'post'

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | titleA |
| 1 | titleB |
| 2 | titleC |

Table 'comment'

| id | id_post | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | blaa |
| 1 | 3 | blbb |
| 2 | 5 | blcc |

Table 'like'

| id | id_comment | vote |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | +1 |
| 1 | 5 | -1 |
| 2 | 5 | +1 |

I need to get a list of post with the most liked comment.

The query sould sum the vote column (+1, -1...) of the table "like" (not the real name) for each comment per post, keep the higest and add it to the corresponding post.

For example:

| post_id | post_title | comment_id | comment_text | like_vote |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | titleA | 12 | blaaaa | 51 |
| 1 | titleB | 25 | blabbb | 98 |
| 2 | titleC | 63 | blaccc | 14 |

```
$statement = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE p.id AS post_id, p.title AS post_title, c.id AS comment_id, c.text AS comment_text, IFNULL(like.like_vote, 0) AS like_vote FROM post p
    LEFT JOIN  (SELECT * FROM comment) c ON p.id = c.id_post
    LEFT JOIN  (SELECT id_comment, IFNULL(SUM(vote), 0) AS like_vote, FROM like GROUP BY id_comment ORDER BY like_vote DESC) like ON c.id = like.id_comment 
    ORDER BY p.id ASC
    ');
```

The result i get is, when a post has 2 comment, i get 2 post with each comment and the count like:

```
post_id: 0, comment_id: 1, like_vote: 5
post_id: 0, comment_id: 2, like_vote: 7
post_id: 1, comment_id: 3, like_vote: 10
post_id: 1, comment_id: 4, like_vote: 3
...
```

Each comment get the correct sum of like but i don't know how to keep only the highest comment and avoid multiple row of post with the same id, like this:

```
post_id: 0, comment_id: 2, like_vote: 7
post_id: 1, comment_id: 3, like_vote: 10
```

If you can help my to build the query it would be very nice, i just don't find it...

Edit: (the name of the table like is just a example to keep things clear)

Comment: Use a cte. Rank the results by post and greatest number of votes, i.e. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY like_vote) as vote_rank`  Then grab `where vote_rank = 1`.  Also, if your table is really named LIKE, consider renaming the table. `like` is a keyword so it's not a good choice for a table name.

Comment: @SOS it's probably the way to go. I was not aware of this function, my sql skills are limited. I need to find the whole query to say if it give the expected result but thanks for the comment

Comment: Updated question tags to indicate you're using 5.x, not 8.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using a CTE. Use [ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) to sort and rank results by post and largest number of votes. Then grab the largest one, i.e. `where votes_rank = 1`

| post_id | comment_id | like_votes | votes_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 7 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 10 | 2 |

**SQL** *(MySQL 8.x)*

*Note - using table name `comment_likes` to avoid having to escape keyword `like`*

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT p.id AS post_id
          , c.id AS comment_id
          , l.like_votes
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
              PARTITION BY p.id
              ORDER BY l.like_votes DESC
          ) AS votes_rank
   FROM   post p 
             LEFT JOIN comment c ON c.id_post = p.id
             LEFT JOIN (
                 SELECT id_comment, SUM(vote) AS like_votes
                 FROM   comment_likes
                 GROUP BY id_comment
             )
             l ON l.id_comment = c.id
)
SELECT * 
FROM   cte
WHERE  votes_rank = 1
AND    like_votes IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY post_id, like_votes
```

**Results:**

| post_id | comment_id | like_votes | votes_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 7 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 10 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=49e7e8d5ea2ad034013294790ff6596c)*

---

**Update 2022-04-01**

MySQL 5.x doesn't support window functions so you'll have to resort to subquery's. Something like this should produce a similar result

```
 SELECT   p.id AS post_id
          , ( SELECT  c.id AS comment_id
               FROM   comment c INNER JOIN comment_likes l ON l.id_comment = c.id
               WHERE  c.id_post = p.id
               GROUP BY c.id
               ORDER BY SUM(vote) DESC
               LIMIT 1
           ) AS comment_id
           , ( SELECT SUM(l.vote) 
               FROM   comment c INNER JOIN comment_likes l ON l.id_comment = c.id
               WHERE  p.id = c.id_post
               GROUP BY c.id
               ORDER BY SUM(l.vote) DESC
               LIMIT 1
           ) AS total_like_votes
 FROM   post p 
 HAVING total_like_votes IS NOT NULL
```

**Results:**

| post_id | comment_id | total_like_votes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 7 |
| 1 | 3 | 10 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4996e13601006248e1e58194289ef2ed)*

Comment: I get a syntax error near `cte AS..., i need to test more if the problem is on my side or not. Maybe my ubuntu server can't do cte ? And the total_votes var seems to come from nowhere, no ?

Comment: Oh wait my bad. The [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b98b240dd1f1b014d78e65ee0c876230) is correct, but the sql above had a typo.  Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but after checking, my server use mysql 5.7 and from what i have understand cte is for mysql-8+. Can this request be converted to a more regular query without cte ?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Wow this is a great answer. I just wonder how to select more colums like if i need `comment_text`in the MySQL 5 query ? Should i repeat a long sub SELECT for every column ?By the way i have upgrade my production server today (with a lot of pain but everything works again) and the cte answer with your latest edit about the DESC is working fine, and it's easy to select more columns. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: That is great. Selecting multiple columns is MUCH easier with 8.x .  Just add them to the SELECT list, right before the ROW_NUMBER(). You only need subqueries with 5.x, which is a less elegant (and bad for performance if there are a lot of them ;-)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2f7395c12839fc3c54aad600a37bdffb

Comment: i need to add something to the cte but can't figure it out. like_votes need to have a bonus like +10 or +20 based on the table comment with a new column userID. This bonus is related to the user ID (if admin or not to make things simple). I have try CASE WHEN ...instead of the simple SUM and it works except when there is no like row. Result is null and the second LEFT JOIN is not executed which give no bonus. I would have null+ bonus in this case. But since vote_rank = 1 is based on the math of like_votes and he is shortcuted... i don't know how to do. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

you can write this query and you will get expected result.

I just rename table like to comment_like coz like is predefined word so is not good practice to use predefined word.

```
    SELECT p.id AS post_id, p.title AS post_title, c.id AS comment_id, c.text AS comment_text, IFNULL(comment_like.like_vote, 0) AS like_vote FROM post p 
LEFT JOIN comment c ON p.id = c.id_post 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_comment, IFNULL(SUM(vote), 0) AS like_vote FROM comment_like GROUP BY id_comment ORDER BY like_vote DESC) comment_like ON c.id = comment_like.id_comment ORDER BY p.id ASC;
```

Comment: I don't see where in this query it filter the result to keep only the most liked comment for each post. You just have clean a bit the query and corrected the last typo i have make w.id -> p.id at the end. The table name is not Lreally lke, it's just to have a very simple example